# Math.abs function in Select statement in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, bigdata

I have the following code in Scala:

```
val FilteredPSPDF = PSPDF.select("accountname","amount", "currency", "datestamp","orderid","transactiontype")
```

However, I have some values in column "amount" which are negative and I need to change them to positive values.  Is it possible to do this arithmetic function within the Select statement? How do I go about this?

Comment: By "change them to positive values" do you mean that you want to take the absolute value of them?

Answer (score 7):

There's an [`abs`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#abs) function available in Spark SQL

You can either use `selectExpr` instead of `select`

```
PSPDF.selectExpr("accountname","abs(amount) as amount", "currency", "datestamp","orderid","transactiontype")
```

or use `select`'s overloaded version that takes columns types:

```
 PSPDF.select($"accountname", abs($"amount").as("amount"), $"currency", $"datestamp", $"orderid", $"transactiontype")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `when` and `negate` *inbuilt function* as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val FilteredPSPDF = PSPDF.select(col("accountname"), when(col("amount") < 0, negate(col("amount"))).otherwise(col("amount")), col("currency"), col("datestamp"),col("orderid"),col("transactiontype"))
```